# Filtering PHP with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, php

I am working on this script that will filter sql results based on the which checkboxes are checked.  My table is set up like so..

```
id   venue    imageurl    showingads    2kandunder  2kto4k   4kandup
1    venue1   myurl.com    yes           yes
2    venue2   myurl.com    yes                       yes
3    venue3   myurl.com    no                                  yes
4    venue4   myurl.com    yes           yes
```

All code is on the same page.  Here is the html..

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="2kandunder" class="checkbox" <?=(isset($_POST['2kandunder'])?' checked':'')?>/> 2kandunder<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="2kto4k" class="checkbox" <?=(isset($_POST['2kto4k'])?' checked':'')?>/> 2k to 4k<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="4kandup" class="checkbox" <?=(isset($_POST['4kandup'])?' checked':'')?>/> 4k and up<br>
</form>
```

Javascript code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(function(){
 $('.checkbox').on('change',function(){
    $('#form').submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

and php...

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";
$dbname = "mydb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }

if (isset($_POST["2kandunder"])) {
$arguments[] = "`2kandunder` = 'yes'";
}
if (isset($_POST["2kto4k"])) {
$arguments[] = "`2kto4k` LIKE 'yes'";
}
if (isset($_POST["4kandup"])) {
$arguments[] = "4kandup LIKE '%yes%'";
}
if(!empty($arguments)) {
$str = implode(' or ',$arguments);

$qry = "SELECT id, venue, imageurl FROM ads where " . $str . "";

$paginate = new pagination($page, $qry, $options);
} else {
//Whatever happens when there's none checked.
$sql = "SELECT id, venue, imageurl FROM ads WHERE `showingads` = 'yes'";
}

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<table class='tablebox' width='940' border='1' cellspacing='5'>
    <tr><td width='75'>".$row["venue"]."</td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td width='10'><a href='post_click.php?id=".$row["id"]."'> <img src='".$row["imageurl"]."'></a></td>
    </tr>"; 


  }
echo "</table>";
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

When I run this page else query displays which is what I want to happen when page first loads.  But when I check any of the checkboxes nothing happens. Here is entire code as it is on page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<html>
<body>
<form id="form" method="post" action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="2kandunder" class="checkbox" <?=(isset($_POST['2kandunder'])?' checked':'')?>/> 2k and under<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="2kto4k" class="checkbox" <?=(isset($_POST['2kto4k'])?' checked':'')?>/> 2k to 4k<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="4kandup" class="checkbox" <?=(isset($_POST['4kandup'])?' checked':'')?>/> 4k and up<br>
 </form>
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(function(){
 $('.checkbox').on('change',function(){
    $('#form').submit();
    });
});
</script>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";
$dbname = "mydb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if (isset($_POST["2kandunder"])) {
 $arguments[] = "`2kandunder` = 'yes'";
}
if (isset($_POST["2kto4k"])) {
$arguments[] = "`2kto4k` LIKE 'yes'";
}
if (isset($_POST["4kandup"])) {
$arguments[] = "4kandup LIKE '%yes%'";
}
if(!empty($arguments)) {
 $str = implode(' or ',$arguments);

 $qry = "SELECT id, venue, imageurl FROM ads where " . $str . "";

 $paginate = new pagination($page, $qry, $options);
} else {
//Whatever happens when there's none checked.
$sql = "SELECT id, venue, imageurl FROM ads WHERE `showingads` = 'yes'";
}

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<table class='tablebox' width='940' border='1' cellspacing='5'>
    <tr><td width='75'>".$row["venue"]."</td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td width='10'><a href='post_click.php?id=".$row["id"]."'> <img src='".$row["imageurl"]."'></a></td>
    </tr>"; 


 }
echo "</table>";
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();

?>
</body>
</html>
```

My first thoughts is 1.  The javascript isn't executing at all?  2. My $arguments is formatted wrong for how I have the database set up? (I have 3 different variations for the arguments to try and test out different formats to see if I could get one to work)

Note:  The php portion from tutorial I learned from had the argument like if (isset($_POST["2kandunder"]).  I have it like this: if (isset($_POST["2kandunder"])) with the extra parenthesis at the end because I was getting a syntax error for each if statement. If that could be the problem why was I getting syntax errors for each if statement line?

All this code and blabbering but I feel like I am close.  Can someone PLEASE help me figure out what the problem is?

**EDIT** 
columns are set up like this..

```
Field    Type          Null    Key    Default     Extra  

id       int(5)         NO     PRI     NULL     auto_increment 

venue   varchar(100)    NO             NULL 

imageurl varchar(150)   NO             NULL 

showingads varchar(5)   NO             NULL 

2kandunder varchar(5)   NO             NULL 

2kto4k  varchar(5)      NO             NULL 

4kandup varchar(5)      NO             NULL
```

**UPDATE**
So I have the checkboxes working now but now when I load the page and click the top checkbox (2kandunder) it returns 0 results. The else sql still works for when no checkboxes are checked.  I changed the first if statement to

```
if (isset($_POST["2kandunder"])) {
$arguments[] = "`showingads` = 'yes'";
```

which should make it the same query as the else sql query when the first (2kandunder) box is checked.  Still 0 results shows.  So I echoed the $qry to display what query was being run when the first checkbox is checked and it is the exact same as the else $sql query but still returns 0 results?  How is this possible if that exact same query works for the else query?

**Last Update**
The problem was the if $results it was only showing results for the sql query thanks for anyone that helped!

Comment: You getting any errors in console ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen No errors.  Just displays the 3 checkboxes on top of page and then displays the date from the else sql query below it.

Comment: can you show me the `ads` and `showing_ads` in sqlfiddle ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen  Not sure how to do that I have never done it before.  I edited my post with how the columns in inside table "ads" is setup

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/on/

You are right. javascript isn't executed at all. You are using jquery 1.4.1. But "on" is available since 1.7
I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  That definitely helped and at least something is happening now when I click a checkbox!  last problem is it is returning 0 results.  Any advice on how to write my arguments if statements correctly?

Comment: if(!empty($arguments)) {
 $str = implode(' or ',$arguments);
//HERE IS --->$qry
 $qry = "SELECT id, venue, imageurl FROM ads where " . $str . "";

 $paginate = new pagination($page, $qry, $options);
} else {
//Whatever happens when there's none checked. 
//HERE IS --->$sql
$sql = "SELECT id, venue, imageurl FROM ads WHERE `showingads` = 'yes'";
}
// YOU ARE USING $sql
$result = $conn->query($sql);


Sorry for CAPS

Comment: And also one advice... Take the echo "<table ... >" out of while. Or Add echo "</table>" to while. Whichever you want. Otherwise it will open tags... but is closed one.